# RTL submenu not aligning properly

Tags: html, css, twitter-bootstrap, nav, arabic-support

I am using bootstrap 4.4.1 for my template and i am trying to create a Nav `RTL` since this is Arabic website menu should show as RTL,

In my Code 5th items from right has submenu  but submenu is not aligning to left of the parent menu as you can see in example as well as screenshot, If i add `right :0;` to `.submenu` then it moves menu to extreme right

also menu doesnt stay on hover it just disappears when i try to move to child items

Not sure where i am doing thing wrong..

[image]

Menu should show up as in below image

[image]

https://codepen.io/KGuide/pen/gOpdLPR

```css
.menu{direction:rtl;}
.header-menu{background:#EEE6D3; min-height:30px; text-align:center;  font-size:18px;}
.header-menu ul {
 margin: 0;
 list-style: none;
 position: relative;
}

.header-menu ul li {
 display: inline-block;
 font-size: 18px;
 font-weight: 600;
}

.header-menu > ul > li > a {
 padding: 15px 30px;
}

.header-menu ul ul li > a {
 font-size: 16px;
 font-weight: 600;
}

.header-menu a {
 display: block;
 padding: 0 10px;
 font-size: 18px;
 font-weight: 700;
 position: relative;
 line-height: 1;
 text-decoration: none;
 color: #555;
 padding: 10px 20px;
 text-transform: uppercase;
}

.header-menu a:hover {
background-color: #A9852D;
color:#fff;
}

.header-menu ul ul {
display: none;
position: absolute;
top: 50px;
background:#EEE6D3;
}

.header-menu ul li:hover > ul {
display: inherit;

}

.header-menu ul ul li {
 min-width: 150px;
 float: none;
 display: list-item;
 position: relative;
}

.header-menu ul ul ul li {
position: relative;
top: -50px;
right: 230px;
}

.header-menu ul ul li {
border-bottom: 1px solid #f5f5f5;
}
```

```html
<div class="container-fluid menu"> 
  <div class="row ">
    <div class="col-12">
  <nav class='header-menu'>
   <ul class="menu-ul">
     <li><a href="#home">الصفحة الرئيسية</a></li>
     <li><a href="#about">من نحن</a></li>
     <li><a href="#poetry">الشعر</a></li>
     <li><a href="#award">الجوائز</a></li>
     <li><a href="#media">قسم الإعلام</a>
     <ul class="submenu">
      <li><a href="#news">NEWS</a></li>
      <li><a href="#videos">VIDEOS</a></li>
     </ul>
     </li>
     <li><a href="#contact">اتصل بنا</a></li>
   </ul>
  </nav>
    </div>
 </div> 
</div>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

### Alignment

The problem has to do with understanding how `position: relative` and `position: absolute` work.

When an absolute-positioned element is placed within an element that has relative positioning - it uses the relative-positioned element to determine its boundaries, which can be utilized for your benefit.

In your case, you can solve your issue by doing this -

```
.header-menu ul li {
    display: inline-block;
    font-size: 18px;
    font-weight: 600;
    position: relative; /* new property */
}

.header-menu ul ul {
    display: none;
    position: absolute;
    top: 50px;
    right: 0; /* new property */
    padding: 0; /* new property to avoid user agent stylesheet polluting */
    background: #EEE6D3;
}
```

Now, because `.header-menu ul ul` is positioned `absolute`ly under `.header-menu ul li` that has relative positioning - it must "abide" to its parent rules and boundaries, and stick to the right of its parent. I hope that's clear.

### Loss of focus on children (irrelevant as OP has solved this already, but leaving for future reference)

As far as your 2nd problem is concerned (not being able to hover over submenu items) - you could solve it by -

1. having no background on `.header-menu ul ul`
2. moving that background to `.header-menu ul ul li`
3. giving `.header-menu ul ul` a slight padding from the top
4. reducing `.header-menu ul ul`'s `top` property by approx. 2 pixels.`

```
.header-menu ul ul {
    display: none;
    position: absolute;
    top: 48px;
    right: 0;
    padding: 2px 0 0 0;
}

.header-menu ul ul li {
    min-width: 150px;
    float: none;
    display: list-item;
    position: relative;
    background: #EEE6D3;
}
```

Rationale: 
You're losing focus because you no longer hover over the element in question.
What we're trying to do by the code I just wrote, is have top padding on the submenu and reducing its distance from the top (thus making the mouse never leave the element itself).

When you hover over the submenu - you're still in the confines of the parent's hierarchy, which makes the menu item not disappear.

Codepen: https://codepen.io/ardethian/pen/MWwqbQM

Comment: Yes this has solved the alignment problem but whenever i move cursor over submenu it hide submenu... This has driving me crazy as i had solved the alignment part also by change the text-align:center to right;

Comment: Just implementex it, Not working for me it still does the same thing..

Comment: @Learning check out the new Codepen at the bottom

Comment: Problem is with the content are in my case, When i added z-index to ` .submenu ` class it solved the problem

Answer (score 2):

Just change `display: inherit;` to `block`.

```css
.header-menu ul li:hover ul {
  display: block;
}
```

**Edit:** To fix the quick hover issue, try to remove the `top` and `padding` properties from `.header-menu ul ul`:

```css
.header-menu ul ul {
  display: none;
  position: absolute;
  /* top: 50px */
  background: #eee6d3;
  padding: 0 /* remove padding */
}
```

https://codepen.io/awran5/pen/vYOzyJm

---

But I encourage you to try [Bootstrap-rtl](https://hamidheidarinia.github.io/bootstrap-rtl/4.2/components/navbar.html)

```html
<link href="https://hamidheidarinia.github.io/bootstrap-rtl/4.2/assets/css/bootstrap-rtl.min.css" rel="stylesheet" />
<script src="https://hamidheidarinia.github.io/bootstrap-rtl/4.2/assets/js/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://hamidheidarinia.github.io/bootstrap-rtl/4.2/assets/js/bootstrap.bundle.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/popper.js/1.12.9/umd/popper.min.js"></script>


<nav class="navbar navbar-expand-lg navbar-light bg-light">
  <a class="navbar-brand" href="#">Navbar</a>
  <button class="navbar-toggler" type="button" data-toggle="collapse" data-target="#navbarSupportedContent" aria-controls="navbarSupportedContent" aria-expanded="false" aria-label="Toggle navigation">
    <span class="navbar-toggler-icon"></span>
  </button>

  <div class="collapse navbar-collapse" id="navbarSupportedContent">
    <ul class="navbar-nav mr-auto">
      <li class="nav-item active">
        <a class="nav-link" href="#">Home <span class="sr-only">(current)</span></a>
      </li>
      <li class="nav-item">
        <a class="nav-link" href="#">Link</a>
      </li>
      <li class="nav-item dropdown">
        <a class="nav-link dropdown-toggle" href="#" id="navbarDropdown" role="button" data-toggle="dropdown" aria-haspopup="true" aria-expanded="false">
          Dropdown
        </a>
        <div class="dropdown-menu
                                                                            dropdown-menu-left" aria-labelledby="navbarDropdown">
          <a class="dropdown-item" href="#">Action</a>
          <a class="dropdown-item" href="#">Another action</a>
          <div class="dropdown-divider"></div>
          <a class="dropdown-item" href="#">Something else here</a>
        </div>
      </li>
      <li class="nav-item">
        <a class="nav-link disabled" href="#" tabindex="-1" aria-disabled="true">Disabled</a>
      </li>
    </ul>
    <form class="form-inline my-2 my-lg-0">
      <input class="form-control mr-sm-2" type="search" placeholder="Search" aria-label="Search">
      <button class="btn btn-outline-success my-2 my-sm-0" type="submit">Search</button>
    </form>
  </div>
</nav>
```

Comment: I am using Bootstrap RTL in my code...  You reply did solve part of problem other issue is when i  mover cursor over submenu specially text area it just hides submenu...

Comment: I Edit the answer, please take a look.

Comment: Can you be specific as its not working on.. did you update pen... It works sometime but most of time it doesnt..

Comment: Problem is with the content are in my case, When i added z-index to ` .submenu ` class it solved the problem

Comment: Sorry. I updated the pen, you need to remove the `top` property as well the padding from `.header-menu ul ul` class.